# Network Drive Initial Connection

Tags: c++, network-drive

This question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029825/network-drive-not-available-on-startup), except for C++.

What is the best way to ensure an initial connection has been made to a network drive before using the path in the software ?

Edit:

To expand a little:

Is/Why isn't there a function like `InitNetworkDriveConnections()` ?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer on the original question? You can just implement the same thing in C++?

Comment: Can't you just try to use it and see if it errors/throws?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a better solution, i.e. InitNetworkDriveConnections() or why doesn't a function like that one exist?

Comment: @MartinJames yes, but the point is to do the connection so I can use it, not just test

Comment: There used to be such a function that was documented for use prior to Windows Vista, called [`WNetRestoreConnectionW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385480(v=vs.85).aspx). If you require compatibility with Vista and later versions of the operating system you will find a fully-coded workaround in the comments section of the  linked page as well. Caveat emptor.