# Read Directories from a Mapped Network Drive

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get all the sub-directories of a `Directory`.

This is the line of code that throws an exception

```
var projectNames = Directory.GetDirectories("Z:").ToList();
```

The Exception is `DirectoryNotFoundException`
I searched in [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directorynotfoundexception?view=net-5.0) and found that this Exception should only be thrown if the Directory is unmapped or does not exist, but here in this case the path exists.

I also tried to search for other reasons that can throw this exception and I found nothing.

Comment: Z: is not a directory. It is drive. do you mean you want to list all directories from a drive ?

Comment: @AmitVerma  Yes, Exactly.  Is it not considered as a `Directory`?

Comment: z:\ is a directory, z: is not. I've crashed into that myself.

Comment: @Clay I tried both, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the Solution, by referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23087325/13176802)

I should Write the Full Path for the mapped drive
such as this

```
var projectNames = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\10.1.7.5\Projects").ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, to get list of directories from drive

```
System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"Z:\");
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

var dir = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
```

Comment: if this has solved problem then accept it so that this can help others.

Comment: I'm implementing this method right now, but it returns the Data as `DirectoryInfo` DataType, even when I convert it `ToString()`, it converts to `char`. I'm testing it now to see what is the output from it.

Comment: ok. Let me know in case you face any issue.

Comment: Tried it, Same Exception

Comment: what is your exact requirement ? Do you need only directory name in the drive or you also need sub directories in directory. Do you need name with complete path ?

Comment: The Main Requirement is to get all the sub-Directories from this Path as a List<string>

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your new rquirement

```
System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"Z:\");
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

//Excluding Hidden and System Directories

List<string> dir = dirInfo.GetDirectories().Where(x=>x.Attributes== FileAttributes.Directory && x.Attributes!=FileAttributes.Hidden && x.Attributes!= FileAttributes.System).Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Same Error >> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\'.'

Comment: it's working on different machines. DO you have z Drive on your machine ? Can you explore more about your z drive.

Comment: Yes, i do have the "Z" Drive on the Machine , it is a Mapped network Drive

Comment: This thing should be mentioned in question.

Comment: I didn't think it would make a difference

Comment: are you able to read from your original drives ?

Comment: Yes, I can.  Also, I reached a solution for this problem,  I should use the full path to the Directory including `server name`.

Comment: great. it means my solution is correct for the original drives as it was in question.

Comment: The Line of Code in the Question works by itself, the issue was the network Drive itself.